# get the current user in the controller symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get the user currently connected to a session.
I mean since we can get the role with this :

```
$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

could we get the user??

Comment: Vamsi's answer is good. Also check out http://www.symfony2cheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the current user like this

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
$user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
```